# Why is the compiler loading this pointer from memory in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, openmp, atomic

I am trying to determine what overhead `std::atomic` introduces to unconditional memory writes on my system (eight-core x64). Here is my benchmark program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    std::atomic_int foo(0); // VERSION 1
    //volatile int foo = 0; // VERSION 2

    #pragma omp parallel
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        foo.store(i, std::memory_order_relaxed); // VERSION 1
        //foo = i; // VERSION 2
    }

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

The program as-is will benchmark `std::atomic_int`, and commenting the lines labeled `VERSION 1` and uncommenting the lines labeled `VERSION 2` will test `volatile int` in its place. Even when unsynchronized, the output of both programs should be 10000000 - 1.

This is my command-line:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 -fopenmp test.c++
```

The version that uses `atomic_int` takes between two and three seconds on my system, while the one that uses `volatile int` almost always completes in less than a tenth of a second.

The salient difference in the assembly is this (output from `diff --side-by-side`):

```
volatile int                        atomic_int
.L2:                                .L2:
    mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax          | mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
                                      > mov DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
    add eax, 1                          add eax, 1
    cmp eax, 10000000                   cmp eax, 10000000
    jne .L2                             jne .L2
    rep ret                             rep ret
```

`rdi` is the first argument to this function that gets run in parallel (it is not modified anywhere in the function), and it is apparently a pointer to (a pointer to, in the second column) the integer `foo`. I do not believe that this extra `mov` is integral to the atomicity guarantee of `atomic_int`.

The extra `mov` is indeed the source of the slowdown for `atomic_int`; moving it above `L2` allows both versions to achieve the same performance and both output the correct number.

When `foo` is made a global variable, `atomic_int` attains the same increased performance of `volatile int`.

My questions are these: Why is the compiler passing a pointer to a pointer in the case of a stack-allocated `atomic_int` but only a pointer in the case of global `atomic_int` or stack-allocated `volatile int`; why is it loading that pointer on every iteration of the loop since it is (I believe) loop-invariant code; and what changes to the C++ source can I make to have `atomic_int` match `volatile int` in this benchmark?

#### Update

Running this program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

//using T = volatile int; // VERSION 1
using T = std::atomic_int; // VERSION 2

void foo(T* ptr) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        //*ptr = i; // VERSION 1
        ptr->store(i, std::memory_order_relaxed); // VERSION2
    }
}

int main() {
    T i { 0 };

    std::thread threads[4];

    for (auto& x : threads)
        x = std::move(std::thread { foo, &i });

    for (auto& x : threads)
        x.join();

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

yields the same, improved performance for both versions 1 and 2, which leads me to believe that it's a peculiarity of OpenMP that forces the worse perf for `atomic_int`. Is OpenMP correct, or is it generating suboptimal code?

Comment: Are you timing the whole program execution? That's useless data. Time the portion of interest.

Comment: @Jeff by modifying the assembly of the two versions myself to confirm that one instruction makes the difference, I have effectively timed the portion of interest.

Comment: Good for you. Since you are the only one who can see the code you're timing, hopefully you can solve your problem, because it's nearly impossible for the rest of us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things get much easier to understand if you look at the intermediate representation (`-fdump-tree-all` is your friend there) of the program rather than at the assembly output.

> Why is the compiler passing a pointer to a pointer in the case of a stack-allocated `atomic_int` but only a pointer in the case of global `atomic_int` or stack-allocated `volatile int`;

This is an implementation detail. GCC transforms parallel regions by outlining them into separate functions that then receive as their sole argument a structure containing all the shared variables, also the initial value of `firstprivate` and placeholders for the final value of `lastprivate` variables. When `foo` is simply an integer and no implicit or explicit `flush` regions are present, the compiler passes a copy of it in the argument to the outlined function:

```
struct omp_data_s
{
   int foo;
};

void main._omp_fn.0(struct omp_data_s *omp_data_i)
{
   ...
   omp_data_i->foo = i;
   ...
}

int main() {
  volatile int foo = 0;

  struct omp_data_s omp_data_o;
  omp_data_o.foo = foo;

  GOMP_parallel(main._omp_fn.0, &omp_data_o, 0, 0);

  foo = omp_data_o.foo;
  ...
}
```

`omp_data_i` is passed via `rdi` (per the x86-64 ABI) and `omp_data_i->foo = i;` compiles to simply `movl %rax, %(rdi)` (given that `i` is stored in `rax`) since `foo` is the first (and only) element of the structure.

When `foo` is `std::atomic_int`, it is no longer an integer but a structure wrapping the integer value. In that case, GCC passes a pointer in the parameter structure rather than the value itself:

```
struct omp_data_s
{
   struct atomic_int *foo;
};

void main._omp_fn.0(struct omp_data_s *omp_data_i)
{
   ...
   __atomic_store_4(&omp_data_i->foo._M_i, i, 0);
   ...
}

int main() {
  struct atomic_int foo;

  struct omp_data_s omp_data_o;
  omp_data_o.foo = &foo;

  GOMP_parallel(main._omp_fn.0, &omp_data_o, 0, 0);

  ...
}
```

In that case, the additional assembly instruction (`movq %(rdi), %rdx`) is the dereference of the first pointer (to the OpenMP data structure), the second one is the atomic write (which on x86-64 is simply a store).

When `foo` is global, it is not passed as part of the argument structure to the outlined code. In that particular case, the code receives a NULL pointer as the argument structure is empty.

```
void main._omp_fn.0(void *omp_data_i)
{
   ...
   __atomic_store_4(&foo._M_i, i, 0);
   ...
}
```

> why is it loading that pointer on every iteration of the loop since it is (I believe) loop-invariant code;

The pointer argument itself (the value of `rdi`) is loop invariant, but the value pointed to might change outside of the function as `foo` is a shared variable. Effectively, GCC treats all variables with OpenMP data-sharing class of `shared` as `volatile`. Again, this is an implementation detail as the OpenMP standard allows for a relaxed consistency memory model where writes to shared variables to do not become visible in other threads unless the `flush` construct is used in both the writer and the reader. GCC is actually taking advantage of that relaxed consistency to optimise the code by passing a copy of some shared variables instead of pointers to the original variables (thus saving one dereference). If there would have been a `flush` region in your code, either explicit

```
foo = i;
#pragma omp flush(foo)
```

or implicit

```
#pragma omp atomic write
foo = i;
```

GCC would have passed a pointer to `foo` instead as seen in the other answer. The reason is that `flush` constructs synchronise the thread's memory view with the global view, in which the shared `foo` refers to the original variable (hence a pointer to it instead of a copy).

> and what changes to the C++ source can I make to have `atomic_int` match `volatile int` in this benchmark?

Besides switching to a different compiler, I can't think of any **portable** change. GCC passes shared variables of structure type (`std::atomic` is a structure) as pointers and that's it.

> Is OpenMP correct, or is it generating suboptimal code?

OpenMP is correct. It is a **multiplaform** specification, which defines specific (and intentionally broad) memory and operational semantics that GCC follows. It might not always give you the best performance for particular case on a particular platform, but then the code is portable and it is relatively easy to go from serial to parallel with the addition of a single pragma.

Of course, the GCC people could certainly learn to optimise better - Intel C++ Compiler already does:

```
                            # LOE rdx ecx
..B1.14:                    # Preds ..B1.15 ..B1.13
    movl      %ecx, %eax                                #13.13
    movl      %eax, (%rdx)                              #13.13
                            # LOE rdx ecx
..B1.15:                    # Preds ..B1.14
    incl      %ecx                                      #12.46
    cmpl      $10000000, %ecx                           #12.34
    jb        ..B1.14       # Prob 99%                  #12.34
```

Comment: Interesting analysis of why gcc misses that optimization.  Your last section saying "OpenMP is correct" is a bit weird, though.  The code *works*, but it's not optimal.  So the right answer to the question is "gcc's OpenMP output is correct but sub-optimal".  From the way you describe it, hoisting the load out of the loop (or passing the pointer directly as a function arg) would be a valid implementation of that source code, like ICC does.  (although hopefully without the silly `movl      %ecx, %eax` that ICC puts inside the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not believe that this extra mov is integral to the atomicity guarantee of atomic_int.

OpenMP seems to think differently. Volatile code with OpenMP atomicity:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    volatile int foo = 0; // VERSION 2

    #pragma omp parallel
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        #pragma omp atomic write
        foo = i; // VERSION 2
    }
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

Assembly output:

```
.L2:
        movq    (%rdi), %rdx
        movl    %eax, (%rdx)
        addl    $1, %eax
        cmpl    $10000000, %eax
        jne     .L2
        ret
```

Comment: I appreciate the discovery, but my three questions still stand.

Comment: @J.doe, as OpenMP was initially created to add multithreading to language without any concurrency and without any atomicity guarantee, it might actually give each thread its own variable and do all atomic synchronisations inside linked library binary. It is hard to optimize code from linked libraries, so it is where those extra operations come from. Just a question, if you link openMP statically, does those extra operations dissapear?

Comment: The instructions appear in the assembly that the compiler optimized and emitted itself, so it's not optimizing code from linked libraries. But, to answer your question, no, statically linking does not alter the instruction sequence.

Comment: @J.Doe , "_The instructions appear in the assembly that the compiler optimized and emitted itself_", Exactly.  It cannot prove that pointer it gets from depth of OMP binary will not change, so it leaves it alone.

Comment: The reason that GCC adds the additional dereference instruction is because there is an implied `flush` region at entry to and exit from the `atomic` operation, which forces GCC to pass a pointer to the original `foo` instead of a temporary copy as it does when `atomic` is not present. It really has nothing to do with the atomicity of the store operation per se.